# What's the inverse function of $ f(x) = 0.02(x-1)^3 + 130(x-1)^{1.5} + 130(x - 1) $?

Tags: inverse, inverse-function, elementary-functions

The equation is graphed here:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kgvnud77dg

I've come up with this equation as part of designing a game. This equation is used to map the user level to their cumulative score. In the game, I only store the user cumulative score. So, I need the inverse function to calculate the level on the fly by simply passing the score.

Example of corresponding Levels and Scores:

Level 1: $ f(1) = 0 $
Level 2: $ f(2) = 260 $
Level 3: $ f(3) = 627 $
Level 4: $ f(4) = 1066 $
Level 5: $ f(5) = 1561 $
Level 10: $ f(10) = 4694 $
Level 50: $ f(50) = 53312 $
Level 100: $f(100) = 160330 $
Level 200: $f(200) = 548423 $

I need to be able to calculate the level using score, like this:
$ f^{-1}(1561) = 5 $

Comment: This is a quadratic equation in disguise.

Comment: Actually the $(x-1)$ in the last term spoils the possibility of solving this as a simple quadratic. If there's a closed form for this (which I am not sure there is), I bet it's very messy. Why do you need an inverse? Perhaps some information on the bigger problem you were trying to solve might help.

Comment: I have added more details to the question. Basically, I'm using this to design a game. I don't mind changing the equation to something simpler and easier to solve, my only concern is to get similar *difficulty* progression.

Comment: This is not a textbook problem, but a **real** problem of a kind of "outsider" who hopes that people with more analytical expertise than he can muster will point him into the right direction. I don't know why MSE should not be a place for such questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, your best bet is not to use the inverse function (whose closed form, if it exists, is probably a horrible mess), but to sample this function at every possible level value that you want (let's hope that you don't want infinite levels) and then when you're given a score, check the index of the score that's immediately lower than it. This works because your function is strictly increasing. In pseudo-code it would look like this :

```
array = [ f(i) for i = 1 to MAX_LEVEL ]

function getLevelFromScore(score)
    for k = 1 to MAX_LEVEL - 1
        if array[k] > score then return k - 1
    return MAX_LEVEL
```

Comment: Your approach would definitely do the trick, I was hoping to avoid that though. If only there was a straightforward inverse function!  

ASIDE:
Another approach is to store the level, which I was hoping to avoid in the first place. Then, I can do operations on the level directly.  

For example, if I wanted to know the score remaining to level up, then $f(level + 1) − score$"

Comment: When you think about it, computing the inverse function for a given argument would probably involve cubic roots, logarithms and whatnot, so in fact doing this approach (or yours) is probably computationally faster anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There are $9$ data points $(x_k,y_k)$ $(1\leq k\leq 9)$. If you define $(\xi_k,\eta_k):=(\log x_k,\log y_k)$, i.e., plot the data on double logarithmic paper, then you can see that, apart from $(\xi_1,\eta_1)$ the $(\xi_k,\eta_k)$ are lying close to a line approximatively given by $\eta=4.4+1.65 \xi$. (So called [regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) can find the optimal values here). Given that, there is a reasonable approximation of the connection between level $x$ and score of $y$ the form $y= c\,x^\alpha$ with $c\approx e^{4.4}$ and $\alpha\approx 1.65$. A relation of this kind can be inverted easily. But note that computationally the solution proposed by @Matrefeytontias might be cheaper and even realize the given data exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's much appreciated. I decided to use a programmatic solution instead, as mentioned by @Matrefeytontias.